# Compact set in $\mathbb R^n$ with maximum metric

Tags: compactness

I dont know how to solve this:
"Show that $A$ is compact, where $A$ is the set of $x \in\mathbb R^n$ which $\|x\|=1,$ with $\|\cdot\|$ is the maximum metric in $\mathbb R^n.$"

My try:
I know that in $\mathbb R^n$: a set is compact iff is bounded and closed.
Well, I know that a set is closed if it is equals to its closure and i also know that the closure of A is equal to (boundary of $A$) union with $A.$
I tried to see what is the boundary of $A$ by the definition: $x$ is in boundary of $A$ iff for all open balls, $B,$ with center in $x$ and radius $> 0$ we have: ($B \cap A$) is not empty and ($B \cap A$'s complementar) is not empty...but i dont know how to get from here... :(

Can anyone hep me, please?

(Sorry for i dont know how to write with codes)

Comment: Perhaps it is easier to show that the complement of $A$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you believe that $||\cdot||_{max}:\Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}$ is continuous, then $A=||\cdot||_{max}^{-1}(\{1\})$ is closed because $\{1\}$ is closed in $\Bbb{R}$. Now you only have to show that is is bounded with respect to the usual metric (which isn't difficult).

Comment: Hi!
I had though it that but how do you prove that the metric is continuous?

Comment: You can prove it by showing that if $(x_n)\to x$ in $\Bbb{R}^n$, then $(||x_n||_{max}) \to ||x||_{max}$ in $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: and without functions, is there any other way to prove it?